# appengine access via oauth2 python script (replacing ClientLogin)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python, oauth2client

I have an App Engine project which:

- uses `google.appengine.api.get_current_user()` to handle users (and `login:required`)
- has a URL to collect some data (which requires login)
- has Google users but on a custom domain

I used to have a script to pull the data using the old `https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin` interface, but now that interface is deprecated, I'm trying to work out what I need to do to get OAuth2 working to access my App Engine URL with a user value set.

I have worked my way through OAuth2 for devices to get myself an access key for my script (i.e. I can run it, authenticate in a web browser, then poll for the access key), as described in [OAuth2 For Devices](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ForDevices).

But I'm not sure:

- what scope I should be using to request the `access_token` compatible with `get_current_user()`,
- how to pass this in my request to App Engine so that it can create the the user header, and
- whether I need to modify my app to use this access_token, eg adding callbacks etc

With regards to the last point, **user** was set by google's front end infrastructure so I’m hoping that that same infrastructure can somehow convert my OAuth `access_token` into a login name without me needing to update my app to do the callback part, because it should all be in appengine's infrastructure right and user is set before the request comes to my app.